# Find the asymtotes to the function: $f(x)={1+ln|x|\over x(1-ln|x|)}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

Find the asymtotes to the function: $f(x)={1+ln|x|\over x(1-ln|x|)}$. I have difficulties with this one when i try to find the limits, i get indefinites that look like (infinity over infinity)over infinity.. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: When is the bottom $0$?

Comment: edited , that would have been easier

Comment: Find when your function has "problems" (ie. when it is not continuous). Also, look at what it does at positive and negative infinity. You may need to use L'Hopital's rule

Answer (score -1):

The important moments in your function's life include $x = 0$ and $\ln |x| = 1$ (so $x = \pm e$), and $x \rightarrow \pm \infty$.

As we go to $\pm \infty$ we get $1 \pm \ln |x| \approx \ln |x|$ so we reduce the expression to approximately $\ln |x| / (-x \ln |x|)$ which divides to simply $-1/x$, so these asymptotes are the horizontal asymptote $y = 0$.

At $x = 0$ the logarithms again overpower the nearby constants, creating something which goes like $-1/x$. But at $0$ this function has a vertical asymptote.

At $x = \pm e$ you'll have vertical asymptotes as the numerator does not go to zero while the denominator does.

It may be helpful to look at a graph of $x f(x)$ as that has the essential "weird" behavior spelled out for you: [WolframAlpha graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+%281+%2B+ln%28%7Cx%7C%29%29+%2F+%281+-+ln%28%7Cx%7C%29%29). This function has a vertical asymptote at $y = -1$ for $x \rightarrow \pm \infty$, and also has a value of $y=-1$ at $0$.